# Dynamic Thresholds in a PromQL query (two labels used in on group filter

Tags: prometheus, promql

The following promql queries with one on group filter (instance) and work as expected to produce a dynamic filter.

```
    - record: threshold_NodeHighCpuLoad_warning
      expr: 10
      labels:
        instance: host.example.net:9100

    - record: threshold_NodeHighCpuLoad_critical
      expr: 85
      labels:
        instance: host.example.net:9100

    - record: query_NodeHighCpuLoad
      expr: 100 - (avg by(app,job,instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
    - alert: NodeHighCpuLoadCritical
      expr:  query_NodeHighCpuLoad > on (instance) group_left() ( threshold_NodeHighCpuLoad_critical or on (instance) query_NodeHighCpuLoad * 0 + 90) or absent (query_NodeHighCpuLoad)*-1
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: Host high CPU load (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
        description: CPU load\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}

    - alert: NodeHighCpuLoadWarning
      expr:  query_NodeHighCpuLoad > on (instance) group_left() ( threshold_NodeHighCpuLoad_warning or on (instance) query_NodeHighCpuLoad * 0 + 80) or absent (query_NodeHighCpuLoad)*-1
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: Host high CPU load (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
        description: CPU load\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}
```

The following promql queries attempts to work with two group filter (container, pod) and does not work.  I suspect it's something to do matching labels.

```
    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning
      expr: 0
      labels:
        container: gitlab

    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_critical
      expr: 1
      labels:
        container: gitlab

    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning
      expr: 1
      labels:
        container: prometheus

    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_critical
      expr: 2
      labels:
        container: prometheus

    - record: query_ContainerHighCpuLoad
      expr: (sum by(pod, namespace, job, instance, image, name, container) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD",image!="",namespace!~"kube-system"}[1m])))

    - alert: ContainerHighCpuLoadWarning
      expr:  query_ContainerHighCpuLoad > on (container,pod) group_left() ( threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning or on (container,pod) query_ContainerHighCpuLoad * 0 + .5) or absent(query_ContainerHighCpuLoad)*-1
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: warning
      annotations:
        summary: Host high CPU load ({{$labels.container}} {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }})
        description: CPU load\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}

    - alert: ContainerHighCpuLoadCritical
      expr:  query_ContainerHighCpuLoad > on (container,pod) group_left() ( threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning or on (container,pod) query_ContainerHighCpuLoad * 0 + 1) or absent(query_ContainerHighCpuLoad)*-1
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: Host high CPU load ({{$labels.container}} {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }})
        description: CPU load\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}
```

I tried adding container as a catchall, as below, but that didn't work.

```
    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_critical
      expr: 1
      labels:
        container: gitlab
        pod: ".*"
```

I suspect it gets evaluated as "=" instead of "=~" and, therefore, doesn't match.

I figured out that if I add the following, I get the expected results.  However, since the pod name is dynamic, I need some sort of regular expression match.

```
    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning
      expr: 0
      labels:
        container: gitlab
        pod: gitlab-67dd9b7d59-np4js

    - record: threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_critical
      expr: 1
      labels:
        container: gitlab
        pod: gitlab-67dd9b7d59-np4js
```

Does anybody know how to address this problem?

Thanks!
-Kendall Chenoweth

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I modified the query to use sum without(label list).

```
   - record: query_ContainerHighCpuLoad
      expr: (sum without(id, node, service, pod, name, image, instance) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD",image!="",namespace!~"kube-system"}[1m])))
```

When it is undesirable to split up time series data by certain label values, like in query_ContainerHighCpuLoad, it is necessary to flag those labels to be ignored.

To figure out which labels are splitting out your time series, start by running the alert promql (next section) expanding the query and including all labels, not required for the join, in the without argument list.  Remove them one at a time in order to determine which ones are a problem and need to be included in the final without list.

Starting with the query.

```
(sum without(id, node, service, name, image, pod, instance, cpu, endpoint, job, metrics_path) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD",image!="",namespace!~"kube-system"}[1m]))) > on (container, namespace) group_left() ( threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning or on (container) (sum without(id, node, service, pod, name, image, instance, cpu, endpoint, job, metrics_path) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD",image!="",namespace!~"kube-system"}[1m]))) * 0 + .4)
```

This exercise results in the following query.

```
(sum without(id, node, service, name, image, pod, instance) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD",image!="",namespace!~"kube-system"}[1m]))) > on (container, namespace) group_left() ( threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning or on (container) (sum without(id, node, service, pod, name, image, instance) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD",image!="",namespace!~"kube-system"}[1m]))) * 0 + .4)
```

Now, you can update the definition of query_ContainerHighCpuLoad and simplify the expression.

```
query_ContainerHighCpuLoad > on (container, namespace) group_left() ( threshold_ContainerHighCpuLoad_warning or on (container) query_ContainerHighCpuLoad * 0 + .4)
```

Because some labels, like instance, are suppressed and relevant to problem resolution, they can be recovered with the following kubectl command.

```
kubectl get po -n monitoring -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{"pod: "}{.metadata.name}/{.metadata.namespace}: {range .spec.containers[*]}{.name}{","}{end}{"\n"}' | grep "prometheus,"
```

In this command the namespace, monitoring,  and container name, prometheus, can be used to extract output such as

```
pod: prometheus-kubeprom-kube-prometheus-s-prometheus-0/monitoring: prometheus,config-reloader,
```

As the query is run against the container name, it could return more than one instance.